# Is there a way to make this switch statement smaller and more professional?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am working to make a Advent Calendar for Christmas and needed to use a switch statement.  My biggest dilemma is the fact that each (daysAway) case opens a new class designed for that day in particular. I am working off of what Google and Stack overflow can provide. I was wondering if there was any other way to compact this?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            //Calculate the days between (date - 12/7/20)
            LocalDate dateBefore = java.time.LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate dateAfter = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.DECEMBER, 25);
            int daysAway = (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateBefore, dateAfter);

            switch(daysAway){
                case 24:
                    openDay1();
                    break;
                case 23:
                    openDay2();
                    break;
                case 22:
                    openDay3;
                    break;
                case 21:
                    openDay4;
                    break;
                case 20:
                    openDay5;
                    break;
                case 19:
                    openDay6;
                    break;
                case 18:
                    openDay7;
                    break;
                case 17:
                    openDay8;
                    break;
                case 16:
                    openDay9;
                    break;
                case 15:
                    openDay10;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    openDay11;
                    break;
                case 13:
                    openDay12;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    openDay13;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    openDay14;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    openDay15;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    openDay16;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    openDay17;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    openDay18;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    openDay19;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    openDay20;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    openDay21;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    openDay22;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    openDay23;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    openDay24;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    openChristmas;
                    break;
                default:
                    notTime.start();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I know it is a giant mess and that is what I am trying to fix!
I appreciate any feedback you can give!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before your next question please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps an array with 25 elements, and use `daysAway` as index into it (first checking that it's a valid index, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Java 14 switch expression syntax:

   ```java
   switch (daysAway) {
       case 24 -> openDay1();
       case 23 -> openDay2();
       case 22 -> openDay3();
       case 21 -> openDay4();
       // ...
       case 4  -> openDay21();
       case 3  -> openDay22();
       case 2  -> openDay23();
       case 1  -> openDay24();
       case 0  -> openChristmas();
       default -> notTime.start();
   }
   ```
2. Since the code is very simple, just collapse it on one line:

   ```java
   switch (daysAway) {
       case 24: openDay1();  break;
       case 23: openDay2();  break;
       case 22: openDay3();  break;
       case 21: openDay4();  break;
       // ...
       case 4:  openDay21(); break;
       case 3:  openDay22(); break;
       case 2:  openDay23(); break;
       case 1:  openDay24(); break;
       case 0:  openChristmas(); break;
       default: notTime.start();
   }
   ```
3. Use an array of Java 8 method references (notice reversed order):

   ```java
   Runnable[] OPEN_METHODS = {
       this::openChristmas,
       this::openDay24,
       this::openDay23,
       this::openDay22,
       this::openDay21,
       // ...
       this::openDay4,
       this::openDay3,
       this::openDay2,
       this::openDay1
   };
   ```

   ```java
   if (daysAway >= 0 && daysAway <= 24) {
       OPEN_METHODS[daysAway].run();
   } else {
       notTime.start();
   }
   ```
4. Since you said that *"each (daysAway) case opens a **new class** designed for that day"*, use an interface (e.g. `Runnable`) and an array of class literals:

   ```java
   Class<?>[] OPEN_CLASSES = {
       OpenChristmas.class,
       OpenDay24.class,
       OpenDay23.class,
       OpenDay22.class,
       OpenDay21.class,
       // ...
       OpenDay4.class,
       OpenDay3.class,
       OpenDay2.class,
       OpenDay1.class
   };
   ```

   ```java
   if (daysAway < 0 || daysAway > 24) {
       notTime.start();
   } else {
       Runnable clazz;
       try {
           clazz = (Runnable) OPEN_CLASSES[daysAway].getConstructor().newInstance();
       } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
           throw new AssertionError("Oops: " + e, e);
       }
       clazz.run();
   }
   ```
5. You can also build the class name dynamically (no array or `switch` statement):

   ```java
   if (daysAway < 0 || daysAway > 24) {
       notTime.start();
   } else {
       String className = (daysAway == 0 ? "OpenChristmas" : "OpenDay" + (25 - daysAway));
       Runnable clazz;
       try {
           clazz = (Runnable) Class.forName(className).getConstructor().newInstance();
       } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
           throw new AssertionError("Oops: " + e, e);
       }
       clazz.run();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (daysAway > 0)
  openDay(25-daysAway); // you haven't shown what you would do here,
         //  but presumably you don't need to write 24 separate functions
else
  notTime.start();
```

Comment: That should be `if (daysAway >= 0 && daysAway <= 24)`